# Unable to connect from Unreal IRC Server to Anope IRC Services

Tags: networking, irc

I am having some issues getting the link to establish from Unreal IRC Server to Anope IRC Services.

I am currently receiving the following error:

```
*** Notice -- No response from services.xxxx.com(irc.localip.com), closing link
```

I am guessing I have something misconfigured. I've been at this for hours. Does anyone know anything about this stuff?  I can upload both unrealircd.conf and services.conf.

Comment: does it really read irc.localip.com? Are you sure services are actually running?

Comment: are you sure those networks arn't just temporary down?

Comment: went to irc.anope.org #anope and they help resolve the issue. Thank you for your assistance.